# How to install HWIOAuthBundle in Symfony4.3?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, hwioauthbundle

If i try install this bundle like it described in docs with command

> composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter
>   php-http/httplug-bundle

i have this error:

```
Problem 1
        - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3].
        - Installation request for php-http/httplug-bundle ^1.16 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug-bundle[1.16.0].
        - php-http/httplug-bundle 1.16.0 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].
        - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.0 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v2.0.0].
        - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.1 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v2.0.0].
        - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v2.0.0
```

if i try to install this packages one by one i have similar output:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3].
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

Is that bundle works with Symfony4.3 ?

\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\\\\===\

Installed successfully with commands:

> composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter=^1.1
>
> composer requirehwi/oauth-bundle php-http/httplug-bundle

as @Taher Ben sassi pointed.

My config.
in security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        oauth:
        resource_owners:
            facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
            google:             "/login/check-google"
            my_custom_provider: "/login/check-custom"
            my_github:          "/login/check-github"
        login_path:        /login
        use_forward:       false
        failure_path:      /login
        provider: users
        oauth_user_provider:
            service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service
```

in services.yaml

```
my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments:
            - '@fos_user.user_manager'
            - ['pass properties as array']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)

1.0 with support for Symfony: ^3.4 & ^4.2.

**Step 1 :**

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter=^1.1
```

**Step 2 :**

```
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/httplug-bundle
```

**composer.json**

```
[...]
"require": {
    [...]
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.6.3",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.13",
    [...]
 }
[...]
```

*UPDATE*.
Mention in GH

Set hwi_oauth in service

```
hwi_oauth:
   firewall_name: secured_area
```

Comment: still have some error:
The service "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a non-exis  
!!    tent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main".

Comment: hwi_oauth is not active in your firewall_name firewall

Comment: I should put  ```hwi_oauth:
   firewall_name: secured_area```
in "config.yaml" file, but in symfony4 there is no such, so where should i put it?
I tried in "security.yaml" and in "services.yaml" but i have error.

Comment: To your security.yaml

Comment: ``` Unrecognized option "hwi_oauth" under "security"```
i have that error

Comment: @Loctarogar In general it is best to stick to one question at a time.  This question was how to install using composer and has been answered.  Consider opening a new question concerning configuration after reading through the bundle's docs and following the examples.

Comment: @Loctarogar I just tried a fresh install and got the same error.  Probably should not have accepted the answer if it did not work.  Bit misleading.  As is all this firewall stuff.  Don't know what the solution is.  Kind of suspect the bundles does not work under 4.3 at all.

Comment: @Cerad as you pointed above the question was how to install. I installed that bundle, but different question how to configure it.

Comment: @Loctarogar The reason I say it is misleading it that the installation did not actually complete.  You got an error message after doing composer require and composer.json was rolled back.  There should not have been any "out of the box" errors.  And while I hope I am wrong, I doubt if any amount of configuration will fix this.  Issue 598 is 5 years old and probably not applicable.  [Open Issue 1553](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1553) might be more applicable.